# way to apply the clipped shape of the path

Tags: inkscape

When you blur an object then it's dimension gets increased, say you only want the blur to happen radially without leaving the circle, this behaviour causes trouble, so you'd have to clip the shape. But, the actual geometry used for clipping is still there(unlike boolean operations), which we may want to get rid of, but if we do get rid of it then the clipping won't remain.

So, say you're ok with the shape you want, and want to 'apply' the non-destructive clipped path to a finalized destructive clip. How would we go about doing that?

EDIT: The endgoal is to create something like this:[image] somehow 'applying' clipping or without using clipping

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. You can't "apply" a clipping path to a blur to finalize it because in Inkscape a blur is an SVG effect - it's not an object as such. The real object would be the underlying vector. You could rasterize it, but then it won't be vector.   Does the finalized image need to be vector?  If it needs to remain vector then why would you need to "finalize" it, i.e. get rid of the clilpping path?  What is the image going to be used for? What problem are you hoping to solve by doing this?

Comment: I intend to use the svg as a scalable graphic in android devices so that that I save hassle of making dimension wise graphic. But the problem is if the dimension changes then this adds to the padding space  making the graphic smaller which is a trouble

Comment: @BillyKerr , how would you bring this effect: https://pasteboard.co/ITUhs5Q.png without clipping? Notice that the boundaries have sharp edge while the inner parts have blur

Comment: I suppose you could [use the Interpolate extension](https://imgur.com/a/9CkVWOw), but it won't look quite the same as a blur.